# Scala: Why does function need type variable in front?

Tags: scala, type-variables

From working on the [first problem of the 99 Scala Puzzles](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/p01.scala) I defined my own version of `last` like so:

```
def last[A](xs: List[A]): A = xs match {
  case x :: Nil => x
  case x :: xs => last(xs)
}
```

My question is: Why is it necessary for `last` to be directly followed by the type variable, as in `last[A]`? Why couldn't the compiler just do the right thing if I wrote the function like so:

```
def last(xs: List[A]): A
    .....
```

(leaving the `[A]` off the end of `last[A]`?)

And if the compiler is capable of figuring it out, then what is the rationale for designing the language this way?

Comment: How would the compiler know that the `A` in `List[A]` doesn't refer to an actual type called `A`?

Comment: I suppose a more lenient compiler, seeing that there is no explicitly declared type `A` in scope, conceivably could introduce an implicit declaration at the most local scope that makes sense.

Comment: `last` is a method, not a function. Functions are declared like this: `val length: List[_] => Int = xs => xs match { case Nil => 0; case x :: xs => 1 + length(xs) }` Note: I don't think you can write `last` as a function since functions can't be polymorphic AFAIK. The closest you can get is `val last: List[Any] => Any = xs => xs match { case x :: Nil => x; case x :: xs => last(xs) }` which is practically useless because you lose any information about the element type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an insight from @Lee's comment:

> How would the compiler know that the A in List[A] doesn't refer to an
>   actual type called A?

To demonstrate to myself that this made sense, I tried substituting the type variable `A`, with the name of an actual type `String`, and then passed the function a `List[Int]`, seeing that when `last` is declared like `def last[String](xs: List[String]): String`, I was able to pass `last` a `List[Int]`:

```
scala> def last[String](xs: List[String]): String = xs match {
     | case x :: Nil => x
     | case x :: xs => last(xs)
     | }
last: [String](xs: List[String])String

scala> last(List(1,2,3,4))
res7: Int = 4
```

Therefore proving the identifier `String` does behave like a type variable, and does not reference the concrete type `String`.

It would also make debugging more difficult if the compiler just assumed that any identifier not in scope was a type variable. It therefore, makes sense to have to declare it at the beginning of the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

`A` appears 3 times:

1. `last[A]`
2. `List[A]`
3. `: A`(after the argument list)

The 2nd one is needed to specify that the `List` contains objects of type `A`. The 3rd one is needed to specify that the function returns an object of type `A`.

The 1st one is where you actually declare `A`, so it could be used in the other two places.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write `last[A]` because `A` does not exist. Since it does not exist, by declaring it after the name of the function you actually get a chance to define some expectations or constraints for this type.

For example: `last[A <: Int]` to enforce the fact that A has to be a subtype of `Int`

Once it's declared, you can use it to define the type of your parameters and your return type.